# How many documents does updateOne effect?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

It would seem that it would simply provide the Update method in the overall CRUD ( Create, Read, Update, Delete. )

However the docs don't seem to make sense ( [Mongoose - updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne) ):

```
const res = await Person.updateOne({ name: 'Jean-Luc Picard' }, { ship: 'USS Enterprise' });
res.n; // Number of documents matched
res.nModified; // Number of documents modified
```

Why is it returning some parameters that count the number of documents matched and modified?

Does it update one or does it update more than one?

Also, what does param1 and param2 refer to in

```
const res = await Person.updateOne(param1, param2);
```

The reference I posted above causes more confusion than help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateOne`, as the name suggests, can update up to *one* document.

It's returning `n` and `nModified` because the that's what the Node.js MongoDB Driver API [returns](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#~updateWriteOpResult) for several update operations (`updateOne`, `updateMany`, `replaceOne`)

`param1` is the filter that you use to query the document(s) to be updated.
`param2` is the change you want to apply for the matched document(s)

`n` *"Number of documents matched"*, means the number of documents that matches the filter, provided as `param1`, for `updateOne` it can be 0 or 1

`nModified` *"Number of documents modified"*, means the number of documents that matches the filter *and* was actually modified because previous value did not match what's given in `param2`, for `updateOne` it can be 0 or 1 (generally less than or equal to `n`)

see also
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Comment: how did you learn mongoose so well? did you know MongoDB first?  Seems the mongoDB docs are a bit better than the Mongoose docs.

Comment: I've been using mongoose for quite a while, I have never used the native mongodb client directly, but I search for reference there sometimes. But the API are somewhat different, so generally just learned to trial & error :)